# Cross Join of List Object items in C# Linq

Tags: c#, linq

i have two object types as below

```
public class A
{
    public int a;
    public int b;
    public int c;
}

public class B
    {
        public int d;
        public string e;
        public string f;
    }
```

I have two lists of the above two classes as below

```
List<A> lista=new List<A>();
lista.Add(new A(){a=10, b=20, c=30});
lista.Add(new A(){a=40, b=50, c=60});
lista.Add(new A(){a=70, b=80, c=90});

List<B> listb=new List<B>();
listb.Add(new B(){d=100, e="hello1", f="world1"});
listb.Add(new B(){d=200, e="hello2", f="world2"}});
```

now I want to create a cross joinf of the above 2 lists with selected fields
eg:

```
[{a=10,b=20,d=100,e="hello1"}, //First item in lista with 1st item in listb
{a=10,b=20,d=200,e="hello2"} //second item in listb with 1st item in lista
{a=40,b=50,d=100,e="hello1"} //Second Item in lista with 1st item in listb
{a=40,b=50,d=200,e="hello2"} //Second Item in lista with 2nd item in listb
{a=70,b=80,d=100,e="hello1"} //Third Item in lista with 1st item in listb
{a=70,b=80,d=200,e="hello2"} //Third Item in lista with 2nd item in listb
]
```

I am not dure how do we achieve this in LINQ ot writing foreach loops is the only go?

Comment: 2 froms, 1 select

Comment: `from a in lista from b in listb select new { a.a, a.b, b.d, b.e }`

Comment: What Mercado said

Answer (score 0):

like this?

```
lista.SelectMany(o=>listb, (o, c)=> new {
    o.a, o.b, c.d, c.e
});
```

Answer (score 0):

In linq query syntax:

```
var cartesianProduct = from a in lista
from b in listb
select new { a.a, a.b, b.d, b.e };
```